# Retrieving records and manipulating them as Ruby objects

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

New to Sequel and SQL in general, so bear with me. I'm using Sequel's `many_through_many` plugin and I retrieve `resources` that are indirectly associated with particular `tasks` through `groups`,  via a `groups_tasks` join table and a `groups_resources` join table. Then when I query `task.resource` on a `Task` dataset I get resource objects in Ruby, like so:

```
>>[#<Resource @values={:id=>2, :group_id=>nil, :display_name=>"some_name"}>, #<Resource @values={:id=>3, :group_id=>nil, :display_name=>"some_other_name"}>]
```

Now, I want to be able to add a new instance variable, `schedule` to these resource objects and do work on it in Ruby. However, every time I query `task.resources` for each task, Sequel is bringing resources objects in to ruby as *different* resource objects each time (which makes sense), despite being the same record in the database:

```
>>
"T3"
#<Resource:0x007fd4ca0c6fd8>
#<Resource:0x007fd4ca0c6920>
#<Resource:0x007fd4ca0c60d8>
#<Resource:0x007fd4ca0c57a0>


"T1"
#<Resource:0x007fd4ca0a4c08>
#<Resource:0x007fd4ca097f58>
#<Resource:0x007fd4ca097b48>


"T2"
#<Resource:0x007fd4ca085ba0>
#<Resource:0x007fd4ca0850d8>
```

I had wanted to just put a setter in `class Resource` and do `resource.schedule = Schedule.new`, but since they're all different objects, each resource is going to have a ton of different schedules. What's the most straightforward way to manipulate these resource objects client side, but maintain their task associations that I query from the server?

Comment: Manipulate them hire? In a way that makes those manipulations visible to all objects holding the same associated row?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, exactly. If I'm creating new objects in Ruby by querying the same from row in my database, it would be great if they were the same object in Ruby-land. Then again, I'll be making many redundant hits to the database, so maybe this isn't the right way to go about this at all?

Comment: Why do they need to be the same object? Sharing state generally just leads to problems. What's your underlying concern?

Comment: @DaveNewton I use the database associations to tell me which tasks can be done by which resources, but then I want to bring this data into Ruby, where I'll use an algorithm to iterate over an array of tasks and assign them to eligible resources. Obviously, I only want a single schedule variable per resource. But if each resource is coming into Ruby as a different object, I'm not sure how to do this. If I were only doing this in Ruby, I would have, say, just 4 resource objects, one for each of 4 people, each with a instance variable `@schedule`. Hopefully Im making sense

Comment: Different objects don't mean different IDs or different comparison results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to retrieve `Resource` objects and then manipulate some attribute named `schedule`. I am not very familiar with Sequel, but looking over the docs it seems to work similarly to ActiveRecord.

1. Set up your instance variable (I imagine using something like `attr_accessor :schedule` on the Resource class).
2. Store the records in a variable, you will be working with same instance each time, rather than the new instance Sequel returns.